# Collision Problems in Processing

Tags: java, processing, collision

So I'm trying to make a platformer game and I'm just starting to work on collision. Right now the collisions very glitchy and only works if its on the side of a rectangle and not the top (this makes more sense if you run the code). I'm wondering how I can get the collision to be cleaner and overall less glitchy.

```
float x = 100;
float y = 100;

float vy = 0;
float vx = 0;

boolean rightCollision = false;
boolean leftCollision = false;

void setup(){
    size(700, 500);
    
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  y += vy;
  vy += .3;
    
  x += vx;
  vx -= vx * 0.07;
    
    
  if(y > 400){
      vy = 0;
      y = 400;
  }
    
  if(left){
      x -= 1;
      vx -= .5;
  }
    
  if(right){
      x += 1;
      vx += .5;
  }
  
  if(touching(x, y, 50, 50, 400, 325, 100, 500) && keyCode == RIGHT){
      rightCollision = true;
  }
  else{
      rightCollision = false;
  }
  
  if(rightCollision){
      vx -= 2;
  }
  
  if(touching(x, y, 50, 50, 400, 325, 100, 500) && keyCode == LEFT){
      leftCollision = true;
  }
  else{
      leftCollision = false;
  }
  
  if(leftCollision){
      vx += 2;
  }
  
  fill(167);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 450, 1000, 50);
  rect(400, 325, 100, 500);
}

boolean left = false;
boolean right = false;

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
      right = true;
  }
    
  if(keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a'){  
    left = true;
  }
    
  if(keyCode == UP || key == 'w'){
    if(y == 400){
      vy -= 10;
    }
    
  }
  
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
    right = false;
  }
  if(keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a'){
    left = false;
   }
}


boolean touching(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float w2, float h2){
    return x1 + w1 >= x2 && x2 + w2 >= x1 && y1 + h1 >= y2 && y2 + h2 >= y1;
}
```

Comment: Try looking up some tutorials. https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection#rectangle-rectangle-collision-detection seems like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect the collision when the player is moving (`vx != 0`, `vy != 0`), not just when the key is pressed.
Set the movement to 0 and limit the player's position when a collision is detected:

```java
int pw = 50, ph = 50;
int ox = 400, oy = 325, ow = 100, oh = 400;
```

```java
topCollision = touching(x, y, pw, ph, ox, oy, ow, oh) && vy > 0.0 && y < oy;
if (topCollision){
    vy = 0;
    y = oy-ph;
}  
  
rightCollision = touching(x, y, pw, ph, ox, oy, ow, oh) && vx < 0.0;
if (rightCollision){
    vx = 0;
    x = ox+ow;
}
  
leftCollision = touching(x, y, pw, ph, ox, oy, ow, oh) && vx > 0.0;
if (leftCollision) {
    vx = 0;
    x = ox-pw;
}
```

Use `>` instread of `>=` for the collision detection:

```py
boolean touching(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float w2, float h2){
    return x1 + w1 > x2 && x2 + w2 > x1 && y1 + h1 > y2 && y2 + h2 > y1;
}
```

[image]